# How to debug in Python: Why doesn't pdb descend into function call?

Tags: python, ipython, pdb, canopy

I've tracked down a bug in which `io.open()` should have been passed `'utf-8'` instead of `'utf8'`. Minimal executable code below. Why doesn't the IPython traceback indicate a line number, and why does [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) neither report that the error was with the `io.open` function call nor report anything from within the the `io.open` code? What could I have done with `pdb` or the IPython debugger or the [Canopy debugger](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy_addons/canopy_debugger/debugger.html) layered on top of it to have had an easier time debugging this one?

Checking my IPython version is also confusing. The Canopy package manager reports that both `ipython 4.0.0-3` and `ipython4 4.0.0-9` are installed, but `import IPython` followed by `IPython.version_info` evaluates to `(2, 4, 1, '')`.

`my_module.py` in Canopy code editor:

```
import io
def my_function(filename):
    with io.open(my_other_function(filename), u'r', u'utf8')
def my_other_function(text):
    return u'modified' + text
```

In the IPython session:

```
In []: import pdb
In []: import my_module
In []: my_module.my_function(filename)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-4c50d9f6cb5c> in <module>()
----> 1 my_module.my_function(filename)

C:\my_module in my_function(filename)

TypeError: an integer is required 

In []: pdb.pm()
> c:\users\bbrown\documents\github\canvasapi-python\capi\my_module.py(3)my_function()
-> with io.open(my_other_function(filename), u'w', u'utf8') as filehandle:

(Pdb) up
> <ipython-input-14-f6d6cc2c1670>(1)<module>()
-> my_module.my_function('testjunk')

(Pdb) down
> c:\users\bbrown\documents\github\canvasapi-python\capi\my_module.py(3)my_function()
-> with io.open(my_other_function(filename), u'w', u'utf8') as filehandle:

(Pdb) args
filename = testjunk

(Pdb) down
*** Newest frame
```

Given that `'utf-8'` works fine as an argument, the `TypeError` is surprising unless originating from within the code of `open`, yet the call to `open` was not placed on the stack, at least not as navigable from `pdb`. Thank you for helping me and others learn how to debug more efficiently!

Comment: Edited to show `my_other_function`. I had removed it from the question when initially writing because I knew the error to be with io.open, but my question is ultimately about how to debug, and the embedded call is what made it opaque for a moment to me.

Comment: Regarding your IPython versions... Canopy GUI's IPython shell uses IPython 2.4.1, which is separate from the IPython installed into your User venv by Package Manager. The IPython installed by Package Manager can be accessed in a Canopy Terminal/ Command Prompt. The "ipython4" package is what is imported with `import IPython` outside of the Canopy GUI and is a dependency of the "ipython" package. This scheme was created to maintain the naming convention for users needing ipython < v4. The "ipython" package installs all dependencies of ipython/jupyter and is what should typically be installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`io.open` is a builtin function:

```
In [8]: import io

In [9]: type(io.open)
Out[9]: builtin_function_or_method
```

It's not written in Python, so there's nothing for the debugger to debug. Your error is caused by improper arguments being passed into `io.open`:

```
open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None,
     errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None) -> file object
```

You passed `'utf-8'` as the third argument, but since `buffering` is supposed to be an integer, the function raised a descriptive `TypeError`. You can fix it by making `encoding` a keyword argument:

```
io.open(filename, mode='r', encoding='utf8')
```

Also, you don't need to import the `io` module explicitly. The `open` builtin is exactly the same function:

```
In [15]: open
Out[15]: <function io.open>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the error, and your explanation about why no code from within open is shown in the traceback makes sense. I'm running Python 2.7, and `open` is `<function open>` while `io.open` is `<function _io.open>`. The `encoding` keyword produces an error with `open` but not with `io.open`.

Comment: I'm still wondering why the call to `io.open` isn't placed on the stack (I suppose because the call was never made because the arguments did not match the Type declared in the C function? And wondering about the IPython version numbers. And wondering if there are debugging techniques that would have made it easier for me to see that problem was with `io.open` rather than `my_other_function` (i.e. a way to know what that function returned without writing it on a separate line of code?